# Execute code outside the android emulator when testing android apps

Tags: android

I'm testing a client-server integration in android. An android app must communicate with a remote mini server, the thing is that when testing the app i'd like to launch the server mini app in the computer, not in the phone:

```
 public class Example {
    MiniServer server;
    ClientApi clientApi;
    @Before public void initialize() {
       //******************* CODE I WANT TO EXEC OUT OF THE EMULATOR  
       server= new miniServer(8081);
       server.run();
       //************************************************************
       clientApi = new ClientApi("localhost",8081);

    }
    @Test public void request1() {
       ...
    }
    @Test public void request2() {
       ...
    }
 }
```

How this can be done ?

Comment: Maybe I there's a sort of " before " code executed in gradle so the code executed in there is in the computer jvm not in the emulator.

Comment: More about a execute a server in diferent thread before testing in gradle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703083/execute-java-program-in-separate-thread-before-running-tests-in-gradle

Answer (score 0):

If I use Robolectric to tests android app the code is executed out of the android emulator.

Here there's how to do it: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/how-to-run-robolectric-junit-tests-in-android-studio/

Then if y want to do instrumental testing with continuos integration i should deploy the web service in gradle before executing the code.